# OpenEdge 10.2A - How to apply the default RETURN / CURSOR-DOWN on Editor widget even if a general code for RETURN / CURSOR-DOWN with ANYWHERE exists?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, enter

I have a code for RETURN / CURSOR-DOWN for all widgets in a window which basically makes it as if TAB is pressed. It works just fine but I want the default functionality of RETURN (Break current line into two lines) / CURSOR-DOWN for EDITOR widgets.

I have tried to add

```
APPLY "ENTER" TO SELF.
```

or

```
APPLY "RETURN" TO SELF.
```

or

```
APPLY "CTRL-J" TO SELF. /*Ctrl-Enter*/
```

for EDITOR widgets but when pressed RETURN / CURSOR-DOWN in an EDITOR it just does not do anything. It stays as if RETURN / CURSOR-DOWN is not pressed.

```
ON RETURN OF {&WINDOW-NAME} ANYWHERE
 DO:
    IF SELF:TYPE="EDITOR" THEN
    DO:
        APPLY "ENTER" TO SELF. /*Does NOT Work*/
    END.
    ELSE IF SELF:TYPE = "BUTTON" THEN
     DO:
         APPLY "Choose".
     END.
     ELSE
     DO:
         APPLY "Tab".
         RETURN NO-APPLY.
     END.
 END.  

ON CURSOR-DOWN OF {&WINDOW-NAME} ANYWHERE
DO:
    IF SELF:TYPE="EDITOR" THEN
    DO:
        APPLY "CURSOR-DOWN" TO SELF. /*Does NOT Work*/
    END.
    ELSE
    DO:
        APPLY "Tab".
        RETURN NO-APPLY.
    END.
END.
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this in 10.2B08. Here's the main anywhere trigger:

```
ON RETURN OF {&WINDOW-NAME} ANYWHERE DO:    
   IF SELF:TYPE = "BUTTON" THEN DO:
      APPLY "Choose".
   END.
   else do: 
      apply 'tab'.
      return no-apply.
   end.
end.
ON CURSOR-DOWN OF {&WINDOW-NAME} ANYWHERE DO:
   if self:type ne 'EDITOR' then DO:
      APPLY "Tab".
      RETURN NO-APPLY.
   END.
END.
```

Not much different from what you had.
Now in the editor, add a trigger to RETURN and one to CURSOR-DOWN.
Here's your editor's RETURN trigger:

```
self:insert-string(chr(13)).
```

And here's the editor's CURSOR-DOWN trigger:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iOffset AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
assign iOffset = self:cursor-char
       self:cursor-line = self:cursor-line + 1 
       self:cursor-char = ioffset no-error.
do while error-status:get-message(1) begins '**Unable to set attribute CURSOR-CHAR':
   assign iOffset = iOffset - 1
          self:cursor-char = ioffset no-error.
   if iOffset = 1 then leave.
end.
```

Let me know if this works for you. Seems to be ok for me here.

Comment: that's great, it works like a charm :) Thank you very much.